# How to convert html element attributes to JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes

I need to convert attribute object to **JSON** type but attribute object is a magic.

**code :**

```
var attrs = $("#delimiter")[0].attributes;
console.log(attrs);
console.log(attrs["id"]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(attrs));
```

**result :**

```
{0: id, 1: title, length: 2}
id=​"delimiter"
{"0":{},"1":{}}
```

I need result like this :

```
{"id" : "foo", "title" : "some title"}
```

Comment: Provide the html too for more clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("#delimiter")[0].attributes` returns an array of attribute nodes with a `name` and a `value` property, so to do what you need you can do:

```
var attrs = {};
$("#delimiter")[0].attributes.forEach(function(element) {
    attrs[element.name] = element.value;
});
```

See the documentation for `Element.attributes` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes).

Comment: i know can create with 'each' can you help me to create with out 'each'

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simple plugin as `$('#delimiter').getAttributes();`

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.getAttributes = function() {
        var attributes = {}; 

        if( this.length ) {
            $.each( this[0].attributes, function( index, attr ) {
                attributes[ attr.name ] = attr.value;
            } ); 
        }

        return attributes;
    };
})(jQuery);
```